# Error in foreign key definition

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys

When I run this code in SQL Server 2005 I get this error:

> Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Foreign key 'FK_Ezn_Qaid_البيان' references invalid column 'اسم_البيان' in referencing table 'Ezn_Qaid'.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Table Ezn_Qaid:

```
create table Ezn_Qaid
(
Qaid_no int NOT NULL ,
Qaid_date nvarchar(10) NOT NULL ,
Maden int NOT NULL ,
Dayn int NOT NULL ,
Qaid_Type nvarchar(15)NOT NULL ,
CONSTRAINT FK_Ezn_Qaid_البيان FOREIGN KEY (اسم_البيان)
REFERENCES البيان(اسم_البيان)  
)
```

And table البيان:

```
create table البيان
(
رقم_البيان int  NOT NULL identity,
اسم_البيان nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Table البيان needs to be created first, and its identity column needs to be a Primary Key:

```
create table البيان(رقم_البيان int  NOT NULL identity PRIMARY KEY 
, اسم_البيان nvarchar(100) NOT NULL); 
GO 

create table Ezn_Qaid ( Qaid_no int NOT NULL , Qaid_date nvarchar(10) NOT NULL 
, Maden int NOT NULL 
, Dayn int NOT NULL
, Qaid_Type nvarchar(15)NOT NULL
, [FK_Ezn_Qaid] int FOREIGN KEY ([FK_Ezn_Qaid]) REFERENCES البيان (رقم_البيان)
)
go
```

Comment: Bear with me on the flipped ) in the first create table statement as as this webform doesn't seem to handle the characters the way I expect.